# JQuery modal dialogue with HTML5 canvas doesn't focus properly

Tags: html, jquery-ui, canvas, modal-dialog, html5-canvas

I have a (complex) HTML5 application that consists of multiple canvases, over which I need to pop up the odd JQuery modal dialogue.

The JQuery modal dialogue does not seem to correctly intercept -any- mouse events (e.g. to move between fields on the form or click buttons). It is possible to tab between fields, and the dialogue otherwise behaves correctly.

Behaviour is the same across multiple browsers.

I have searched high and low, but cannot find any specific guidance for the use of JQuery UI with canvas/multiple canvases and/or mouse event intercept related issues. Any pointers gratefully received. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting `pointer-events: none;` on the canvases. That will allow the mouse events to be ignored by them and bubble up to your dialog properly.